# How to make MacBook auto switch graphics judging by its power type?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, graphics

I want my MacBook to use Integrated Graphics when running on battery power and use Discrete Graphics when running on external power automatically. I can easily do this on Windows, but I couldn't find any setting to do this on macOS. So I wonder, is there any way I can do this on my MacBook, running El Capitan?

Comment: gfxCardStatus is the standard graphics switching tool, but they removed this feature, as discussed at the bottom of https://gfx.io/switching.html

Comment: I find the tool in GitHub before,But it didn't work on my MacBook